# Installed Spyder and trying to connect to database but receiving error

Tags: database, postgresql, api, connection, spyder

I am learning data analysis with Python and just downloaded Spyder.
This is my command to connect to the PostgreSQL Database I want to work with:

(Editted)

```
import psycopg2
pip install psycopg2-binary
pip install psycopg2
python setup.py build
sudo python setup.py install
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=*** user=*** password=***")
```

But already for the first line I get the following error:
*runfile('C:/Users/.../.spyder-py3/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/.../.spyder-py3')
File "C:\Users....spyder-py3\untitled0.py", line 16
pip install psycopg2-binary
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax*

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't see `import psycopg2`. When reporting an error message, include the entire message not your edited version.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I added the import statement and the line runs, but the same error appears now at the second line

Comment: Well the `ipip` and `python` commands are system shell commands and should not be run in Python program. You will need to be more specific about where you arerrunning this?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I am running them directly in the Spyder Editor

Comment: Then that is not going to work. The `pip` and `python` commands need to run at the system command line, not in a Python program.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver sorry, I have a problem understanding the terminology. Is the system command line equivalent to the commands in spyder console?

Comment: No you would need to open a Windows `cmd` terminal. I'm guessing you already have `psycopg2` installed anyway as `import psycopg2` does not fail.

Comment: I have Anaconda Prompt. Is that where I would paste commands from my initial question?

Comment: You are not paying attention. You cannot mix system commands and Python commands. Also it looks like you already have `psycopg2` installed so you don't need to run the install commands anyway. You really need to spend some time with basic tutorials on Python and the command line.